# Replace the item in collection with a new item

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

I have a observablecollection Named A with properties id,age,name, Am storing the changed things in another collection B. Now I want to replace the same item in object A with that of changed things in B .How can I achieve it.

```
foreach(var item in A)
{
}
```

Comment: Is both collection properties are same?

Comment: yes, I need to replace the items in B with the same index of A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Zip operator

```
        ObservableCollection<ObjType> obsCollectionA = new ObservableCollection<ObjType>();
        ObservableCollection<ObjType> obsCollectionB = new ObservableCollection<ObjType>();

        foreach (var pair in obsCollectionA.Zip(obsCollectionB, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }))
        {                
            pair.A.Id   =   pair.B.Id;
            pair.A.Name =   pair.B.Name;
            pair.A.Age  =   pair.B.Age;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from "yes, I need to replace the items in B with the same index of A"

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
{
    B[i] = A[i];  //or A[i] = B[i];
    // You could compare by: if(A[i].ID == B[i].ID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way:

```
public static IList<T> Swap<T>(this IList<T> list, int indexA, int indexB)
{
    if (indexB > -1 && indexB < list.Count)
    {
        T tmp = list[indexA];
        list[indexA] = list[indexB];
        list[indexB] = tmp;
    }
    return list;
}
```